# Django - Celery - supervisord logging configuration

Tags: django, logging, celery, supervisord

i have a django project with celery task (running inside), but i have a question about logging, what i have done is:

**Task logging get_task_logger :**

```
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
logger = get_task_logger('celery')
```

**Django logging:**

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'root': {
    'level': 'DEBUG',
    'handlers': ['sentry', 'file'],
},
'formatters': {
    'verbose': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'console': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'verbose',
    },
    'celery': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'stream': sys.stdout,
    },
 ........
},
'loggers': {
    'celery': {
        'handlers': ['celery'],
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
......
},
```

**supervisord celery config:**

- [program:celery]
  *command=/usr/local/bin/celery worker -A app --autoscale=20,10 -E -l INFO -Ofair
- directory=/xxx/celerydir
- numprocs=1
- stdout_logfile=/xxx/logs/celery_worker.log
- stderr_logfile=/xxx/logs/celery_worker_err.log
- autostart=true
- autorestart=true
- startsecs=10
- stopwaitsecs=600
- stopasgroup=true
- priority=998

My problem is as you can see, inside Django -> celery handler i've specified "'stream': sys.stdout", but when i start celery with supervisord i will see both logs 
*celery_worker.log* and *celery_worker_err.log* that store all logs for all level : INFO, WARNING, ERROR... why?

**How can i configure logger for celery to redirect all celery log only to stdout and let supervisord store level info only on *celery_worker.log* ?**

thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think it's because by default celery reports things to stderr instead of stdout,
you can use supervisord redirect_stderr = true flag to combine two files into one if that helps.

There's a settings in celery that let's you specify a log-file if log-file is not specified it uses stderr.